# Authorship-verified website not included in "Author Stats" of Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, google-authorship

In Google Webmaster Tools, is it normal for a website for which the Structured Data Testing Tool shows that "Authorship is working for this webpage" -- to ***not*** be listed in the "Author Stats" section (under "Labs")?

I already understand that successful verification using the Structured Data Testing Tool does *not* guarantee that Google will actually display authorship in the SERPs, and that Google decides this at its own discretion.

However, shouldn't such successful verification at least guarantee that the website *is* included in the "Author Stats" section (which purportedly covers "pages for which you are the verified author")?

I would have assumed that, if Google is not yet displaying authorship for that site, it would show both its Impressions and Clicks as being "<10".

Are my assumptions incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorship snippets are not guaranteed to be displayed, even if implemented in a technically correct way. When these aren't shown, they are not counted in the authorship statistics. It only uses "<10" to display those where the number is >=1 & <10.